# Button not working using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, button

I added html code using javascript. All the headings and divs are working fine except the Button. The Button is not added or may be not working for some reasons. Please check my code give some suggestions. When I used the same code as html it worked fine.

```
var ItemsToAdd = '';
ItemsToAdd += '<h5 style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px; font-size:30px;" >' + app.categories[0].name + '</h5>\
                       <div><img src="' + app.info_icon_path + '" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px; float:left;"  alt="Info_image"/></div>\
                       <div > <a data-role="button"  style="margin-top:135px; margin-left:5px; width:136px; height:50px; float:left;">Load</a></div>\
                       <div>\
                            <h5 style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;font-size:30px;" >' + app.name + '</h5>\
                            <p style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:20px">' + app.desc_short + '<br></br></p>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="ui-block-d"> <a data-role="button"  style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:5px; width:136px; height:50px; float:left;">more info</a>\
                        </div>\
                        <p><br><br><br></p>\
                        <h5 style="margin-top:30px; margin-left:10px;font-size:20px;" >Version ' + app.version + '</h5>\
                        <h5 style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;font-size:20px;" >' + app.price + '</h5>';

$("#content2").append(ItemsToAdd);
```

Comment: can you do a JsFiddle?

Comment: What you are doing with buttons. Maybe your events are not attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use updated library JQuerymobile. And you need to refresh the dynamically add HTML element.

Finally use

```
$("#content2").trigger('create');
```

Comment: Thanks budy....it worked by just adding $("#content2").trigger('create'); after $("#content2").append(ItemsToAdd);

Comment: @naki `$("#content2").append(ItemsToAdd).trigger("create");`

Answer (score 0):

Use cannot add dynamic html directly in mobile jquery you need to use "Refresh" or use .button() method in Jquery mobile for dynamic appearance of Jquery mobile UI...

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html

you can look here http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/ for more details

```
  $("#addbutton2_here").append('<a data-role="button">' + getTime() + '</a>');
  $("#addbutton2_here").find("a[data-role='button']").button();
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/P4sLY/)